# typescript lib array omits dom, but libdom is included in compiliation

Tags: typescript

I do not want lib dom included in my compiliation, outright.

My tsconfig looks like this:

```
{
  lib: ["es2020"]
}
```

Sure enough, I cannot reference DOM entities in my src/* modules! This is desirable.

However, when I compile with `skipLibCheck: false`, one of my augmentations for a `Request/Response` entity (see @types/node@18+) *conflicts* with libdom!

How can I figure out why libdom is in my compilation?